# Scrapy - Get 2 values split between span tag

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm using Scrapy to scrapy a table on a page:

```
import scrapy
from ..items import TestItem
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'

    def parse(self, response):
        items = response.xpath('//*[@id="12"]/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr')
        for l in items:
            il = ItemLoader(item=TestItem(), selector=l)
            # From should be text before <span></span> and To should be after
            il.add_xpath('from', 'td[2]')
            il.add_xpath('to', 'td[2]')
            yield il.load_item()
        pass
```

Sample Data:

```
<tr>
<td class="test">date</td>
<td class="test2">London<span></span>Prague</td>
</tr>
```

I need to submit the "London" text to "from", and "Prague" to "to". In other words, how do i split the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
items = response.xpath('//*[@id="12"]/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr')
for l in items:
    tf = l.xpath('./td[@class="test2"]//text()').getall()
    il = ItemLoader(item=TestItem(), selector=l)
    # From should be text before <span></span> and To should be after
    il.add_value('from', tf[0])
    il.add_value('to', tf[1])
    yield il.load_item()
```